# CSS DIV and span priority

Tags: html, css

Hi hoping you all can help.

The CSS below features a navbar and a main div. Within the main div there are tooltip spans which allow a tooltip to appear over the text when hovered over.

The issue I am having is that the text within the tooltip spans are not 'hidden' or covered by the navbar div when the user scrolls down.

I want the navbar div to sit on top of everything.

The HTML text: `<b>Test text that works fine... the Lorem Ipsum text below does not fall behind the navbar though</b><br><br>`

is doing exactly what I want. When the user scrolls the navbar div sits on top of the text. The text in the tooltip span however, doesn't.

What is happening:

[image: current output]

Expected output:

[image: expected output]

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0px 0px 10px 16px;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.main {
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: 80px;
  height: 1500px; 
}


.ttooltip {
  position: relative;
}

.ttooltip .ttooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;

    /* z-index: 1; */

    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    position: absolute;

    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.ttooltip .ttooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.ttooltip:hover .ttooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>

<body>

<div class="navbar"><h2>Hello world</h2></div> 


<div class="main">

<b>Test text that works fine... the Lorem Ipsum text below does not fall behind the navbar though</b><br><br>

<span class="ttooltip">orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<span class="ttooltiptext">Tooltip text!</span>


</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the `z-index` which specifies the stack order of an element. So an element on `z-index: 10` will show under an element with z-index `30` for example.

So, what you should do in your navbar class is something like this (you can change the z-index number if you want):

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0px 0px 10px 16px;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;

  /* What you should add */
  z-index: 1000
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your .navbar class like this:

```
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0px 0px 10px 16px;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: Answers should have explanations